Incorrect digit detection using Tesseract OCR on video frames in Python
I'm trying to calculate the real time of video recording. I have a lot of videos, some of which were lost during transmission. All of them are in mp4 format. to get the duration, I recognize the time using pytesseract.image_to_string, but I get incorrect results.
My approach involves capturing the frames, preprocessing the images, and using Tesseract to extract the text. However, the digit recognition is often incorrect or inconsistent.
The image on which the code recognizes the numbers is incorrect:

The above image gives a similar answer
the time is calculated from 'data2/20240619_191208_first_frame.jpg' 19:12:66
The full code looks like this:
def digit_detect(image):
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config='--psm 6 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789:')
    return text

def resize_roi(image, x1 = 131, y1 = 11, x2 = 228, y2  = 32):
    roi = image[y1:y2, x1:x2]
    return roi

def preprocess_image(image):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    return binary

# def extract_time_from_image(image):

#     regions = [
#         (131, 11, 142, 31, '012'),         # Tens of hours (0-2)
#         (142, 11, 155, 31, '0123456789'),  # Units of hours (0-9)
#         (163, 11, 179, 31, '012345'),      # Tens of minutes (0-5)
#         (179, 11, 193, 31, '0123456789'),  # Units of minutes (0-9)
#         (202, 11, 215, 31, '012345'),      # Tens of seconds (0-5)
#         (215, 11, 226, 31, '0123456789')   # Units of seconds (0-9)
#     ]

#     digits = []

#     for (x1, y1, x2, y2, whitelist) in regions:

#         preprocess = preprocess_image(image)
      
#         resized_roi = resize_roi(preprocess, x1, y1, x2, y2)


#         custom_config = f'--psm 6 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist={whitelist}'
#         digit = pytesseract.image_to_string(resized_roi, config=custom_config)
      
#         digits.append(digit)

#     return digits
    

folder_path = 'data/output_rec/rkbt/1' 
load_path = "data2"

if not os.path.isdir(folder_path):
    print(f"Error1")
    exit()

video_files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith('.mp4')]

for video_file in video_files:
    video_path = os.path.join(folder_path, video_file)

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

    if not cap.isOpened():
        print(f"Error2")
        continue

    total_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

    ret, first_frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print(f"Error3")
        cap.release()
        continue

    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, total_frames - 1)

    ret, last_frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print(f"Error3")
        cap.release()
        continue

    cap.release()

    first_frame = resize_roi(first_frame)
    last_frame = resize_roi(last_frame)

    first_frame = preprocess_image(first_frame)
    last_frame = preprocess_image(last_frame)

    # print(extract_time_from_image(first_frame))
    # print(extract_time_from_image(last_frame))

    first_frame_path = os.path.join(load_path, f"{os.path.splitext(video_file)[0]}_first_frame.jpg")
    last_frame_path = os.path.join(load_path, f"{os.path.splitext(video_file)[0]}_last_frame.jpg")

    print(f"the time is calculated from '{first_frame_path}'" , digit_detect(first_frame))
    print(f"the time is calculated from '{last_frame_path}'" , digit_detect(last_frame))

    cv2.imwrite(first_frame_path, first_frame)
    cv2.imwrite(last_frame_path, last_frame)

    print(f"Saved images with the first and last frames for '{video_file}'")



I tried to recognize each digit separately, limiting the many possible options.
I also used various variations of image binarization and various parameters of pytesseract.image_to_string


Honestly, this looks like the kind of simplified case where a student's-first-model type project trained on images from the specific data source you care about would probably work adequately. Remember that Tesseract is very old software, built primarily with high(ish, compared to video/screen resolutions)-resolution scans of print material in mind.

if image is too small then tesseract can have problem to recognize it. If margin around digit is too small then it can also have problem. It may need to resize and use erosion or bluring.

See also the Is there a Minimum Text Size? (It won't read screen text!) entry in Tesseract's FAQ.

tesseract doc: Improving the quality of the output | tessdoc

I took your image and use directly tesseract image.jpg  (without processing and without using Python, and without any parameters) and it gives me correct result. Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.1.1 with Leptonica. It show only warning "Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead."
